# How to get recently created child object in one soql

Tags: apex, soql, aggregate

I have 2 objects, Portfolio__c and batch__c. We can create batches against portfolio (i.e) batch__c has a lookup field to Portfolio__c.  I have a VF page which was showing a list of portfolios and the latest batch created for that portfolio. The VF page uses a repeater which is bound to a list of Wrapper class. The logic I use for filling the wrapper list is shown below.

```
foreach portfolio
{
 Wrapper wrp = new Wrapper();
 wrp.portfolioId=....;
 wrp.CreatedDate = (Datetime)([select max(createddate) maxdate from Batch__c  where Portfolio__r.Id != null and Portfolio__r.Id =: wrp.portfolioId][0].get('maxdate'));
 lstBatch = [select Id,Name,Status__c, (SELECT Asset__r.Id FROM BatchItem__r) from  Batch__c where Portfolio__r.Id =: wrp.portfolioId and CreatedDate =: wrp.CreatedDate ];    
.
.
.
lstWrapper.Add(wrp);         
}
```

Is there a way available to get most recently created batch and its details in one soql query?

Comment: Could you post your real and formatted code?

Comment: @Martin Lezer: Sorry. I am not allowed to post it. It will be against my company policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery -

```
[Select Id, ..(Select Id from Batch__c order by createdDate DESC) from Portfolio__c]
```

Or else you can follow same process which you are using above and order by PortfolioId and createdDate

```
select Id,Name,Status__c, (SELECT Asset__r.Id FROM BatchItem__r) from  Batch__c where Portfolio__r.Id =: wrp.portfolioId Order By ProtfolioId, CreatedDate DESC
```

Comment: I added LIMIT 1 in the second query. It works. Thanks